Mass-replace [rest] and [api] with [magento-rest-api] in questions about the Magento REST API?
I recently created the tag magento-rest-api as I noticed there are a lot of questions about it, but now I would like to add it to past questions.
There are 200+ questions with the tags magento+rest+api1. IMO the tags rest and api are too vague to be meaningful in this context: these questions are not specifically about REST nor about building an API in general, but about the Magento REST API, hence the new tag.
Would it be possible to mass-edit the tags of these questions? I would like to replace magento+rest+api with magento+magento-rest-api.

[1]: strangely, [magento] [rest] [api] magento rest API -[magento-rest-api] shows 219 results, but [magento] [rest] [api] -[magento-rest-api] shows only 95 ones.

"strangely, [magento] [rest] [api] magento rest API -[magento-rest-api] shows 219 results, but [magento] [rest] [api] -[magento-rest-api] shows only 95 ones." because the latter does a tag search therefore only shows you questions. The former is performing regular search that has tags as part of the criteria. It shows you questions and answers. Using [magento] [rest] [api] magento rest API -[magento-rest-api] is:q returns 95 results

"IMO the tags rest and api are too vague to be meaningful in this context" essentially, they are almost never relevant and almost always misused. Not just this context. If you see a question with the [[tag:api]] tag, then it's pretty much guaranteed that the tag doesn't apply (without even going into the "DO NOT USE" guidance on the tag). Basically the same with [[tag:rest]]. Both together all but guarantee that the question is about something else, not these two tags. Overall the conclusion from this is that [magento]+[api] and [magento]+[rest] probably also need a look.

There are no such mass edit tools that are available to perform this task. Moderator tools only permit replacing a single tag with another and do not handle compound replacement. Staff may have tooling for this but the threshold to perform such replacement is typically much higher than a few hundred posts and an escalation would almost certainly take longer than a manual replacement (assuming the community agreed that this was the correct course of action).

To clarify, that tool is to replace all occurrences of a single tag in all non-deleted questions with another tag. There is no capability to bulk-replace only the occurrences of the tag in posts matching any criteria.

[tag:rest] is probably still fine to keep--shouldn't anyone who is familiar with REST APIs theoretically be able to answer a question about Magento's REST API?

@TylerH Theorically yes but in practice 1- you need some knowledge of Magento because the documentation of the API is insufficient to answer 99% of the questions and 2- some questions are not about consuming the API but about extending it to add new endpoints, which requires some Magento/Symfony knowledge.

@TylerH REST is just a way to organize service layout for the Internet (well, doesn't need to be HTTP-based, but usually is). It doesn't actually concern itself with using these services. A user knowledgeable in RESTful services would be able to tell you how to lay out endpoints and the semantics of HTTP verbs and status codes. That's about it. Asking them to answer Magento API questions would be about as meaningful as asking some model-view-controller architect for how to use some software that was built with MVM. Not a lot of transferrable knowledge.

The worst thing is that "REST" is extremely often misused to mean something along the lines of "something something HTTP call". Usually when I see the tag, people aren't asking about RESTful services/architecture. They might want to call some endpoint or maybe use data from a call. Or otherwise the service they ask being RESTful or not has zero impact. Because they aren't asking about the architecture, just for something and there is an HTTP call involved. [[tag:rest]] is most often just noise. Almost as bad as [[tag:api]].

Asking for a specific REST API would also require specific knowledge. Somebody who is an expert with the Stack Exchange API would have very little transferable knowledge for, say, the Azure DevOps API. Or the Heroku API. Or SonarQube API. Or kanyerest...which is apparently "REST API for random Kanye West quotes".

@VLAZ Fair enough!
